# Xamarin forms firebase push notification edit the message content before display

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I am new to xamarin forms and tryig to **modify** the notification content before displaying it. I am using ***data payload*** only.

Problem : I can see the modified content message and also the normal message( before modify content) also. *This issue is when the app is in **background***, foreground I can see only modified message. How do I cancel the previous message, I want to show only the modified message.

I used this [tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-push-notifications-xamarin-forms) to display the firebase message using package Plugin.FirebasePushNotification

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
{
   ModifyMsgAsync(this, p).Wait();
}            

ModifyMsgAsync(Context context, FirebasePushNotificationDataEventArgs message)
{
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "123");
builder.SetContentTitle("Changed the title");
builder.SetContentText("Message body is changed");

builder.SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh);
builder.SetAutoCancel(true); //disappear after sometime
NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);
managerCompat.Notify(notification_id, builder.Build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is, when app is in background system process the notification message using the default channel.

Solution: The solution is after modifying the content delete the default channel to not to process the system handled message. this solve the issue.

```
[Application]
    public class MKApplication : Application
    {
        

        public MKApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            //Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
            
            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're sending a message with a `notification` key in there. When the user is not actively using the app, such messages are handled by the system - which means that your code has no way to control how the message is displayed.

If you always want your code to handle the display of the message, send messages with **only** a `data` key in there.

Also see the Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

Comment: Sorry, I am using data message only but two message arr displaying one with modified and other without modified